# Campo Selectonemenu(Primefaces) não salva no banco

Tags: java, jsf, hibernate, primefaces

Venho pedir a ajuda de vocês novamente, pois preciso terminar meu TCC.
Eu tenho um `dialog` que possui vários campos, um deles é um `<p:selectOneMenu>`. Quando preeencho todos os campos e vou salvar, os campos são todos salvos, menos o campo `<p:selectOneMenu>`. E não aparece nenhum erro no stacktrace.
Já debuguei, pesquisei sobre `Converter` e outras mil coisas...e nada de solucionar.

**ATUALIZAÇÃO**

Observando as consultas do Hibernate, percebi que ele faz o `insert` em todos os campos, menos na classe auxiliar `monografia_linhapesquisa`,pois tenho um relacionamento `Manytomany` entre `Monografia` e `LinhaPesquisa`
Abaixo a saída do console:

> Hibernate: 
>       insert 
>       into
>           monografia
>           (aluno_id, data_inicio, professor_id, titulo) 
>       values
>           (?, ?, ?, ?)

Tenho o seguinte mapeamento entre `Monografia` e `LinhaPesquisa`. Na classe `LinhaPesquisa` não fiz nenhum relacionamento

```
@ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name="monografia_linhapesquisa", joinColumns=
    {@JoinColumn(name="monografia_id")}, inverseJoinColumns=
    {@JoinColumn(name="linha_pesquisa_id")})
    private List<LinhaPesquisa> listaLinhaPesquisas;
```

Meu `<p:selectOneMenu>`

```
        <p:outputLabel value="Linha de Pesquisa: " for="linhaPesquisa" />
            <p:selectOneMenu id="linhaPesquisa" converter="#{gestaoMonografiasBean.linhaPesquisaConverter}"
                value="#{gestaoMonografiasBean.monografia.linhaPesquisa}" required="true" >
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione..." />
                <f:selectItems value="#{gestaoMonografiasBean.selecionarLinhaPesquisa}"
                    var="linhaPesquisa" itemLabel="#{linhaPesquisa.titulo}"
                    itemValue="#{linhaPesquisa}" />
            </p:selectOneMenu>
```

Meu método `selecionarLinhaPesquisa` que fica no meu `bean`, que uso para acessar o repositório de `Linha de Pesquisa`, depois de buscar passo a lista para o `Converter`

```
public List<LinhaPesquisa> getSelecionarLinhaPesquisa() {
        List<LinhaPesquisa> listaLinhaPesquisas = linhaPesquisas.todas();

        linhaPesquisaConverter = new LinhaPesquisaConverter(listaLinhaPesquisas);

        return listaLinhaPesquisas;
    }
```

Meu método que faz a busca no banco

```
public List<LinhaPesquisa> todas() {
        return manager.createQuery("from LinhaPesquisa", LinhaPesquisa.class).getResultList();
   }
```

E por último meu `Converter`, que acho que está funcionando normal, pois debuguei e vi que chega no método getAsObject o `id` referente a `Linha de Pesquisa` selecionada, porém não salva no banco.

```
package com.daniel.monografia.controller.converter;

import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.convert.Converter;
import javax.faces.convert.ConverterException;

import com.daniel.monografia.model.LinhaPesquisa;

public class LinhaPesquisaConverter implements Converter {

    private List<LinhaPesquisa> listaLinhaPesquisas;



    public LinhaPesquisaConverter(List<LinhaPesquisa> listaLinhaPesquisas) {
        this.listaLinhaPesquisas = listaLinhaPesquisas;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        System.out.println("Objeto linha pesquisa: " + value);
        if (value == null || value.isEmpty()) {
            throw new ConverterException("Erro de Conversão: value null ou vazio");

        }

         Long id = Long.valueOf(value);

         for(LinhaPesquisa linhaPesquisa: listaLinhaPesquisas){
         if(id.equals(linhaPesquisa.getId())){ 
             return linhaPesquisa; 
            } 
         }

         return null;

    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        System.out.println("Strinh linha de pesquisa: "+value);

        if(value == null){
            return "";
        }

        try{
            if(value instanceof LinhaPesquisa && value != null){

                return String.valueOf(((LinhaPesquisa) value).getId());
            }else{

            }
        }catch(NumberFormatException e){
            throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage(String.format("Selecione uma Linha de Pesquisa", value)), e);
        }
        return null;

    }

}
```

Meu método para buscar a lista de `Linhas de Pesquisa` do meu `bean`, que pego os objetos para persistir no objeto `monografia`

```
public List<LinhaPesquisa> getSelecionarLinhaPesquisa() {
        List<LinhaPesquisa> listaLinhaPesquisas = linhaPesquisas.todas();

        linhaPesquisaConverter = new LinhaPesquisaConverter(listaLinhaPesquisas);

        return listaLinhaPesquisas;
    }
```

O método `todas()` no  repositório `linhasPesquisas`

```
public List<LinhaPesquisa> todas() {
        return manager.createQuery("from LinhaPesquisa", LinhaPesquisa.class).getResultList();
   }
```

O bean `GestaoMonografiasBean` completo

```
package com.daniel.monografia.controller;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.convert.Converter;
import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

import org.primefaces.context.RequestContext;

import com.daniel.monografia.controller.converter.AlunoConverter;
import com.daniel.monografia.controller.converter.LinhaPesquisaConverter;
import com.daniel.monografia.controller.converter.ProfessorConverter;
import com.daniel.monografia.model.Aluno;
import com.daniel.monografia.model.LinhaPesquisa;
import com.daniel.monografia.model.Monografia;
import com.daniel.monografia.model.Pessoa;
import com.daniel.monografia.model.Professor;
import com.daniel.monografia.repository.Alunos;
import com.daniel.monografia.repository.LinhaPesquisas;
import com.daniel.monografia.repository.Monografias;
import com.daniel.monografia.repository.Professores;
import com.daniel.monografia.service.CadastroMonografiaService;
import com.daniel.monografia.util.FacesMessages;

@Named
@ViewScoped
public class GestaoMonografiasBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Inject
    private Monografias monografias;

    @Inject
    private FacesMessages messages;

    @Inject
    private Professores professores;

    @Inject
    private Alunos alunos;

    @Inject
    private LinhaPesquisas linhaPesquisas;

    @Inject
    private CadastroMonografiaService cadastroMonografiaService;

    private List<Monografia> listaMonografias;

    private List<LinhaPesquisa> listaLinhaPesquisas;

    private String termoPesquisa;

    private Converter professorConverter;

    private Converter alunoConverter;

    private Converter linhaPesquisaConverter;

    private Monografia monografia;

    private Aluno aluno;

    private Professor professor;



    @PostConstruct
    private void iniciar() {
        monografia = new Monografia();

        aluno = new Aluno();
        this.aluno.setPessoa(new Pessoa());

        professor = new Professor();
        this.professor.setPessoa(new Pessoa());

        listaLinhaPesquisas = linhaPesquisas.todas();


    }

    public void prepararNovaMonografia() {

    }

    public void prepararEdicao() {
        professorConverter = new ProfessorConverter(Arrays.asList(monografia.getProfessor()));
        alunoConverter = new AlunoConverter(Arrays.asList(monografia.getAluno()));
    }

    public void salvar() {
        System.out.println("*********************Objeto: ***********************" + monografia);
        try {
            cadastroMonografiaService.salvar(monografia);

            atualizarRegistros();

            messages.info("Monografia salva com sucesso!");

            RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update(Arrays.asList("frm:monografiasDataTable", "frm:messages"));

        } catch (Exception erro) {
            erro.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void excluir() {
        cadastroMonografiaService.excluir(monografia);

        monografia = null;

        atualizarRegistros();

        messages.info("Monografia excluída com sucesso!");
    }

    public void pesquisar() {
        listaMonografias = monografias.pesquisar(termoPesquisa);

        if (listaMonografias.isEmpty()) {
            messages.info("Sua consulta não retornou registros.");
        }
    }

    public void todasMonografias() {
        listaMonografias = monografias.todas();
    }

    public List<Professor> completarProfessor(String termo) {
        List<Professor> listaProfessores = professores.pesquisar(termo);

        professorConverter = new ProfessorConverter(listaProfessores);

        return listaProfessores;
    }

    public List<Aluno> completarAluno(String termo) {
        List<Aluno> listaAlunos = alunos.pesquisar(termo);

        alunoConverter = new AlunoConverter(listaAlunos);

        return listaAlunos;
    }

    public List<LinhaPesquisa> getSelecionarLinhaPesquisa() {
        List<LinhaPesquisa> listaLinhaPesquisas = linhaPesquisas.todas();

        linhaPesquisaConverter = new LinhaPesquisaConverter(listaLinhaPesquisas);

        return listaLinhaPesquisas;
    }

    private void atualizarRegistros() {
        if (jaHouvePesquisa()) {
            pesquisar();
        } else {
            todasMonografias();
        }
    }

    private boolean jaHouvePesquisa() {
        return termoPesquisa != null && !"".equals(termoPesquisa);
    }

    public List<Monografia> getListaMonografias() {
        return listaMonografias;
    }

    public List<LinhaPesquisa> getListaLinhaPesquisas() {
        return listaLinhaPesquisas;
    }

    public void setListaLinhaPesquisas(List<LinhaPesquisa> listaLinhaPesquisas) {
        this.listaLinhaPesquisas = listaLinhaPesquisas;
    }

    public String getTermoPesquisa() {
        return termoPesquisa;
    }

    public void setTermoPesquisa(String termoPesquisa) {
        this.termoPesquisa = termoPesquisa;
    }

    public Converter getProfessorConverter() {
        return professorConverter;
    }

    public void setProfessorConverter(Converter professorConverter) {
        this.professorConverter = professorConverter;
    }

    public Converter getAlunoConverter() {
        return alunoConverter;
    }

    public void setAlunoConverter(Converter alunoConverter) {
        this.alunoConverter = alunoConverter;
    }

    public Converter getLinhaPesquisaConverter() {
        return linhaPesquisaConverter;
    }

    public void setLinhaPesquisaConverter(Converter linhaPesquisaConverter) {
        this.linhaPesquisaConverter = linhaPesquisaConverter;
    }

    public Monografia getMonografia() {
        return monografia;
    }

    public void setMonografia(Monografia monografia) {
        this.monografia = monografia;
    }

    public Aluno getAluno() {
        return aluno;
    }

    public void setAluno(Aluno aluno) {
        this.aluno = aluno;
    }

    public boolean isMonografiaSeleciona() {
        return monografia != null && monografia.getId() != null;
    }
}
```

A classe `Monografia` que faz o relacionamento `ManytoMany` com a classe `LinhaPesquisa`

```
package com.daniel.monografia.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.persistence.Transient;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Past;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;

@Entity
@Table(name="monografia")
public class Monografia implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 120)
    private String titulo;

    @NotNull
    @Past
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "data_inicio")
    private Date dataInicio;


    @NotNull
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "aluno_id")
    private Aluno aluno;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "professor_id")
    private Professor professor;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name="monografia_linhapesquisa", joinColumns=
    {@JoinColumn(name="monografia_id")}, inverseJoinColumns=
    {@JoinColumn(name="linha_pesquisa_id")})
    private List<LinhaPesquisa> listaLinhaPesquisas; 

    @Transient
    private LinhaPesquisa linhaPesquisa;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitulo() {
        return titulo;
    }

    public void setTitulo(String titulo) {
        this.titulo = titulo;
    }


    public Date getDataInicio() {
        return dataInicio;
    }

    public void setDataInicio(Date dataInicio) {
        this.dataInicio = dataInicio;
    }

    public List<LinhaPesquisa> getLinhaPesquisas() {
        return listaLinhaPesquisas;
    }

    public void setLinhaPesquisas(List<LinhaPesquisa> linhaPesquisas) {
        this.listaLinhaPesquisas = linhaPesquisas;
    }

    public Aluno getAluno() {
        return aluno;
    }

    public void setAluno(Aluno aluno) {
        this.aluno = aluno;
    }

    public Professor getProfessor() {
        return professor;
    }

    public void setProfessor(Professor professor) {
        this.professor = professor;
    }

    public LinhaPesquisa getLinhaPesquisa() {
        return linhaPesquisa;
    }

    public void setLinhaPesquisa(LinhaPesquisa linhaPesquisa) {
        this.linhaPesquisa = linhaPesquisa;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Monografia other = (Monografia) obj;
        if (id == null) {
            if (other.id != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Monografia [id=" + id + "]";
    }
}
```

Comment: Alguém poderia dar uma força?

Comment: Qual o objeto você está tentando persistir? Onde está a implementação dele? Me parece que você não está setando o valor do objeto persistido de acordo com o que está sendo selecionado do selectOneMenu.

Comment: Valeu @KaranAlvesPereira vou atualizar o post, obrigado desde já pela ajuda

Comment: No debug você observou se na hora de salvar o objeto monografia, o monografia.linhaPesquisa está preenchido ?

Comment: Sim está preenchido. Com id e titulo

Comment: @Douglas Obrigado pela ajuda. Vou colocar a classe `Monografia` que possui o mapemaneto ManytoMany com a classe `LinhaPesquisa`, estou desconfiando que o relacionamento não está correto. No caso estou trabalhando com uma classe auxiliar `monografia_linhapesquisa` e eacho que ela não está recebendo o ``monografia_id` e `linha_pesquisa_id`

Comment: Não sei se é isso mesmo, mas eu acho que o JPA/Hibernate não está persistendo a tabela auxiliar `monografia_linhapesquisa` que contém a chave `monografia_id` e `linha_pesqusia_id`
Desculpa, mas deve ser um problema básico e eu não vejo pois sou novato nesse mundo

Comment: @KaranAlvesPereira  Atualizei o post. Percebi que o hibernate não faz o insert nem update na tabela `monografia_linhapesquisa`

Comment: Por que o mapeamento está como @ManyToMany, se você está utilizando o componente selectOneMenu que permite selecionar apenas um registro?

Comment: @KaranAlvesPereira Muito obrigado cara! Usei o componente `<p:selectCheckboxMenu>` e mostrou a atributo no datatable, agora tem um outro problema, ele só mostra um atributo, eu quero que ele mostre todos que foram selecionados.
E desculpa por te importunar com esse erro bobo de principiante, você me ajudou no meu TCC, valeu!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1 -**  Você está usando o mapeamento @ManyToMany para um componente que permite selecionar apenas 1 registro.

**Solução:** Trocar o componente para selectCheckboxMenu

**2 -** No datatable ele só mostra um atributo, eu quero que ele mostre 
todos que foram selecionados

**Solução 1:** Como este campo é um List, sugiro criar um novo campo na sua entidade que apresente as informações da lista concatenadas e separadas por virgula. No get desse campo, você pode fazer um for em cima da List para retornar essa informações. Depois no dataTable, basta informar esse campo que criasse.

**Solução 2:** Você pode sobrescrever o método ToString() da sua lista e retornar da forma que vc quiser, chamando a própria lista no dataTable.